# Jekyll unable to locate default layout

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have the following folder tree:
[image]

My index.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
---
<h1>{{ "Hello World!" | downcase }}</h1>
```

My default.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ include navigation.html }}
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

My navigation.html:

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about.html">About</a>
</nav>
```

My about.md:

```
---
layout: default
title: About
---
# About page

This page tells you a little bit about me.
```

I am following the official documentation on the [Jekyll website](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/). I am receiving the following build warning for my page:

```
Configuration file: none
            Source: /Users/doug/Documents/portfolio
       Destination: /Users/doug/Documents/portfolio/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
     Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in root/about.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in root/index.html does not exist.
                    done in 0.038 seconds.  Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/doug/Documents/portfolio'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000   Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Do you have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here? I keep look over my code and comparing it but can't identify where I am wrong. I'm sure it is something silly.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to run the following from the root folder:

```
jekyll serve
```

Referencing the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/benbalter/wordpress-to-jekyll-exporter/issues/37).